# Resolving paths in href

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, href

I have my `href` attribute set as:

```
<a href="/somePage"></a>
```

But I migrated my page from localhost to www.example.com, and now path to `/somePage` looks like `www.example.com/myApp/somePage` instead of `localhost/somePage`.

How can I make my `href` attribute correctly redirect to `/somePage`, no matter which prefixes I would add?

Comment: Is `somePage` always relative to the current document or to the site root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use use a . (dot) for assign the relative  path

```
   <a href="./somePage"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is typically solved by using server-side code to automatically generate links by using references to other documents so that wherever they move, the links stay correct.

For static pages however, it becomes more of a challenge.

My recommendation is to avoid the problem of migration altogether by debugging locally on a custom internal domain.

If you know your site is going to be published to `www.example.com/myApp`, then I recommend setting up a `www.example.local` domain with your site in `www.example.local/myApp` when you do local testing. That way, when you publish all your relative and root-relative paths will work as expected.

---

If you can't do this, then you're going to need to start using relative paths everywhere which come with their own issues. The [`<base>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-base-element) can also help occasionally, but I don't generally recommend its use as it can be confusing to debug.